# Proving the four lemma using members

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, diagram-chasing

I am struggling with exercise VIII.4.2 in Mac Lane's *Categories for the working mathematician*. 
The exercise is about proving the four lemma about being an epimorphism using members in abelian categories (Borceux calls these **pseudo-elements**).

I am trying to adapt the proof in the category of abelian groups to use members, but I am getting stuck near the end.

My proof so far goes like this:

Let $x \in_m b_3$. Since $f_4$ is an epimorphism, by Theorem $3(iii)$ we find $y \in_m a_4$ such that $f_4y \equiv h_3x$. Since $f_5$ is a monomorphism, $g_4y\equiv 0$ and by Theorem $3(v)$ we find $z \in_m a_3$ satisfying $g_3z \equiv y$. Now $h_3f_3z \equiv f_4g_3z \equiv f_4y \equiv h_3x$, so by Theorem $3(vi)$ we find some $a \in_m b_3$ satisfying $h_3a\equiv 0$ (among other things). By Theorem $3(v)$, this gives $b \in_m b_2$ such that $h_2b \equiv a$, and by 3(iii) we have a $c \in_m a_2$ satisfying $f_2c \equiv b$.

Now in the proof for abelian groups, we could show that $f_3(g_2c + z) = x$ (maybe up to sign, depending on how exactly $a$ was defined), but I don't see how to apply Theorem $3(vi)$ in the correct way to do this.

Here are the definition of members and Theorem 3:
[image: Definition of members and start of Theorem 3]
[image: The rest of Theorem 3]

Here is the statement of the Five Lemma:
[image: Statement of the Five Lemma]

And here is the exercise in question:
[image: The exercise in question]

Comment: Maybe you can adapt the statement of 3.(vi) and actually define the $a$ that works ? You should be able to define it in a way that resembles the case of abelian groups, and use that definition to do the same argument as in that case.